# Does winpcap/libpcap allow me to send raw wireless packets?

Tags: windows, wireless, winpcap

I've been using winpcap to send raw packets over a wired connection for a while now. I'm building my own protocol (nothing special, just getting the hang of it) but now I want to extend it to wireless connections too. Does winpcap allow me to send raw packets over a wireless adapter?

I'm using VC++ on windows xp and windows 7. On my windows 7 machine it seems to work, but on my xp machine winpcap can't even open my adapter to send/receive packets. I tried to launch wireshark on my xp machine to see if the packets sent from my other machine arrived, but I wireshark couldn't open my wireless adapter either. Then rebooted into ubuntu and tried again. This time the wireshark did work, but the packets didn't show up.

Is there anything I should know about winpcap's limitations regarding wireless transmission? And if there are limitations is there an alternative that can let me send raw packets over wireless network on windows?

Comment: 1. writing your own low-level protocol is generally a bad idea, you'd better stick at least to ip, at best to tcp or udp, with your own application layer on top of it.

Comment: 2. windows allows to send raw packets without resorting to libpcap.

Comment: @adrien: access to RAW sockets on Windows is restricted to admin users only, though.

Comment: On top of that, raw sockets are not supported (or are restricted) in windows xp sp2+ until windows 7. And below only by windows xp sp 1. So I think that using winpcap/lipcap is a more portable approach. @Adrien, the protocol I'm writing is never going to be used for anything serious. It's just for amusement and because I want to see if I can get computers to communicate the ways want them to.

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas left? How can I send raw packets over a wireless network?

Answer (score 1):

If "raw" means "raw 802.11 packets", then *libpcap* might allow it, but *WinPcap*, not so much.  See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34454592/raw-wifi-packets-with-winpcap/34461313#34461313).  If you can put the adapter into monitor mode on Linux, *BSD, or OS X, you might be able to send raw 802.11 packets.  On Windows, however, not only is putting it into monitor mode going to take a significant amount of work (probably including new *kernel-mode* code!), once you've put it into monitor mode, it might be impossible to send *any* packets.

If "raw" just means "raw IP packets", then raw IP sockets should work as well - or not well - as on Ethernet.