# Raw WiFi Packets with WinPcap

Tags: c, wifi, raw-sockets, winpcap

Consider the simple C code to [send a single raw packet](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut8.html) with WinPcap. The lines related with building the packet header starts with the following comment:

> /* Supposing to be on ethernet, set mac destination to 1:1:1:1:1:1 */

Therefore you might guess that, in order to send a Raw WiFi Packet, you should change this block of the code accordingly.

However, this is not the case. You can send a Raw WiFi Packet without changing one single line of that code, just filling the right MAC addresses. The same is true when [capturing packets](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut3.html), instead of WiFi headers the packets will have Ethernet headers.

After some searching, it seems that this issue is related with Windows emulating a 'fake ethernet' when passing the packets to WinPcap. Unfortunately I couldn't find much more details about it.

**1st Issue**
How this 'fake ethernet' works? Is it possible to bypass it or disable it?

**2nd Issue**
Is it possible to have full control over the WiFi headers? (even if this require something else than WinPcap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How this 'fake ethernet' works?

Either the network adapter itself supplies packets to the host with fake Ethernet headers (transforming the 802.11 MAC, LLC, and SNAP headers into an Ethernet header and, for some packets, an LLC header possibly followed by a SNAP header), or the driver does so.

This is only done for data frames; management and control frames are not shown when capturing in this mode.  The source and destination MAC addresses of the 802.11 header become the source and destination MAC addresses in the Ethernet header; the TA and RA fields are discarded, as are the frame control and other fields in the header.  If the frame has a SNAP header with an OUI of all zeroes, meaning "the PID is an Ethernet type", the PID in the SNAP header becomes the value in the type/length field of the Ethernet header; otherwise, the length of the data in the frame, including the LLC header and everything after it (but not including the FCS) becomes the value in the type/length field.  Everything after the SNAP header in the first case, and everything after the MAC header in the second case, becomes the Ethernet payload.

> Is it possible to bypass it or disable it?

Yes, but you'll have to install special software on your machine.

Some forms of special software have names such as "Fedora" and "Ubuntu". Unfortunately, they might cause problems when trying to run Windows applications on your machine. :-)

Unfortunately, as you're trying to *send* packets, trying to do this *without* replacing Windows with Linux isn't as easy as installing Microsoft Network Monitor and capturing traffic with that.  Unfortunately, [Microsoft's documentation for "Network Monitor Operation Mode" for "Native WiFi"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff568369.aspx) says that, in that mode, "The driver cannot send packets either on its own or through a call to its *MiniportSendNetBufferLists* function."  Perhaps there are ways of connecting to the Wi-Fi driver the same way some of the user-mode boxes in the diagram on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560683(v=vs.85).aspx) do, but, to find them, you might have to start at [Microsoft's top-level documentation page for Native 802.11 Wireless LAN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff560690.aspx) and work your way down.

Comment: _trying to do this without replacing Windows with Linux_ I'm trying to send a simple beacon packet such that any WiFi computer in the range could capture it without the cumbersome of joining a particular network connection beforehand. However, as simple as it sounds, under Windows it would be necessary to re-write the NIC driver (bizarre). Do you consider that such simple beacon packet would be easier to code under Linux instead of Windows?

Comment: "Do you consider that such simple beacon packet would be easier to code under Linux instead of Windows?"  Unless there's some simple way to get at the code paths that the user-mode portion of Native WLAN uses, yes, it would be a *lot* easier, even if you end up using raw `PF_PACKET` sockets rather than using libpcap on Linux.

Comment: Ever heard of [Acrylic WiFi](https://www.acrylicwifi.com)? It claims to enable the monitor mode under Windows. Apparently they've developed a NDIS driver compatible with several standard NIC's.

Comment: Either that or they implemented a driver, similar to the WinPcap driver, that uses NDIS 6 to support Native WLAN with underlying NIC drivers that already support it; from a quick look at Acrylic's site, that's my guess.  Unfortunately, that means they would have the limitations of Native WLAN, such as "it captures packets but doesn't support sending them".

Comment: It seems that the first versions of [Windows XP has support for raw sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_socket#Implementations). In that case, do you consider more feasible to code the aforementioned beacon packet under Windows XP? (ie: no re-writing of drivers or kernel)

Comment: As far as I know, raw sockets on Windows will not give you any ability to send or receive raw Wi-Fi packets.  They may let you send arbitrary *IP* packets, but that's a different matter.

Comment: Unfortunately you're right, winsock api doesn't provide support to data-link level (at most to raw IP packets). I also considered using WinXP with WinPcap but, after some searching, it seems that there would be the same problem discussed above with disabled monitor mode (probably fake ethernet also). I guess there is no simple way to avoid Linux. Let me know if you don't agree with that. Thanks for your help!