# Can you use WinPcap to send and receive IP packets at the same time?

Tags: sockets, networking, winpcap

I read this answer:

> On Windows, however, not only is putting it into monitor mode going to take a significant amount of work (probably including new kernel-mode code!), once you've put it into monitor mode, it might be impossible to send any packets.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34461349/6906871

Would that mean you can't send and receive IP packets at the same time using WinPcap? For example, let's say you want to make a modified version of the TCP protocol and call this the Lefauder protocol. These Lefauder protocol packets can be sent by using raw sockets. You write an application to send raw IP packets using WinPcap and parse incoming packets, which are replies from the server to the Lefauder protocol packets that were sent, with the same application and/or and use Wireshark at the same time to check if the packets are sent correctly.

Comment: It has nothing to do with WinPCAP. If you want to see all the traffic, even that which is not intended for you, you must use monitor mode. When in monitor mode, the Wi-Fi interface is not usable for normal network traffic. You can use WinPCAP on an interface in normal mode, but the interface will ignore any traffic not destined for your host, so WinPCAP will only see traffic for your host.

Comment: @RonMaupin So, would you actually be able to do what is described in the example in my post?

Comment: As long as you are not trying to see any traffic not destined for your host. If you want to see all the traffic on the wireless LAN, then you cannot do what you want.